# How do you safely delete file directory references with Assets 2 installed?

Tags: assets

I moved most of my images to an S3 source and the migration went well. However I left a couple of images lurking in the old 'filesystem' folders (and thus the associated references)

When I then deleted my old File Upload Preferences references, and then visited a Publish page, I got a PHP exception error with `unknown_source` referred.

It appears that when Assets still has references to old folders in the DB, and those folders are deleted, it throws an exception.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the latest versions of [Assets ( now up to 2.0.4)](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets/releasenotes)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably remnants left in the DB related to the old file directory paths.

Dig into the database to see where the Assets data is stored. It's probably in its own table and will be named accordingly. Look for data cells which contain the file upload tag `{filedir_1}` or {filedir_2} or whatever the number is... The full data will look similar to `{filedir_1}/imagename.png`. The {filedir_1} part is linking back to the old file directory path used in your File Upload Preferences.

Once you've confirmed that this is indeed the issue, then you'll need to decide what to do from there. You can build a query to remove this part of the data or you can clear all those cells...

If you need help with the query, post the details into a new questions.